# PHP updating MS SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

Obviously, I need a second pair of eyes to review this as I can't seem to find the error(s)...

The data pulls back correctly into the form as it should. However, when I change the data, such as adding extra m's on the end of the email address, I get the message "Settings Updated Successfully". But checking the database the database shows nothing updated.

```
<?php

session_start();
include ("../../includes.php");
include ("../../configs/configDashboard.php");

$Squery="Select IDX, AgencyID, username, password, email,
FBSAgencyID, MBSAgencyID, CETAgencyID,
jurisdiction, pageafterlogin,
CASE when FBS=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as FBS, 
CASE when MBS=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as MBS,
CASE when CET=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as CET,
CASE when adminuser=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as adminuser, 
CASE when InventorySearch=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as InventorySearch,
CASE when Inactive=1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' End as Inactive
from tblUsers where IDX = '14'";


$Sresult = sqlsrv_query($Sconn, $Squery) ;

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Sresult,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inventory Dashboard</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 -->
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.0/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins 
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.chartphp.com/wp-content/uploads/favicon.png">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="../../lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../lib/js/chartphp.js"></script>
    <script src="../../lib/js/chartphp-l.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/js/chartphp.css">

    <style>
        /* white color data labels */
        .jqplot-data-label{color:white;}

        .jqplot-table-legend td {
            font-size: 115%;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }

        /* white color data labels */
        .jqplot-point-label{color:white;}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body class="skin-black">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="http://www.southernsoftware.com" class="logo"><img src="../../SmallLogo-Horizontal.png" height="35" width="auto"></a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          </a>
          <img src="../../Badge.jpg" height="42" width="42" align="left"><h3><strong><?php echo $AgencyName?></strong></h3>
          <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
        </nav>

      </header>

      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">

          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
          <?php include ("../../sidebarmenu.php")?>
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

      <div class="row">

            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <div class="box box-success">
                <div class="box-header with-border" id="groupbarrests">
                 <h3 class="box-title">Dashboard Settings</h3>
                  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body no padding">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="pad">

                        <?php
//$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)

{

$username =$_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$AgencyID =$_POST['AgencyID'];
$FBSAgencyID =$_POST['FBSAgencyID'];
$MBSAgencyID =$_POST['MBSAgencyID'];
$CETAgencyID =$_POST['CETAgencyID'];
$jurisdiction =$_POST['jurisdiction'];
$FBS =$_POST['FBS'];
$MBS =$_POST['MBS'];
$CET =$_POST['CET'];
$pageafterlogin =$_POST['pageafterlogin'];
$adminuser =$_POST['adminuser'];
$InventorySearch =$_POST['InventorySearch'];
$Inactive =$_POST['Inactive'];

//$FBSIndexIncTypeExcludeOther =$_POST['FBSIndexIncTypeExcludeOther'];
//$FBSIndexIncTypeExcludeOther= isset($my_array['FBSIndexIncTypeExcludeOther']) ? $my_array['FBSIndexIncTypeExcludeOther'] : "";

$update="update tblUsers set username='".$username."', password='".base64_encode($password)."',email='".$email."'
, jurisdiction='".$jurisdiction."', FBS='".$FBS."', MBS='".$MBS."'
, CET='".$CET."', pageafterlogin='".$pageafterlogin."', adminuser='".$adminuser."'
, InventorySearch='".$InventorySearch."', Inactive='".$Inactive."' 
Where IDX = '14'
"; 

sqlsrv_query($Sconn, $update) ;
$arr = sqlsrv_errors();
foreach ($arr as $value) { echo $value; };

$status = "Settings Updated Successfully. </br></br>";
echo $status;
//header ("Location: settings.php");
}else {

?>

<div>
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />


<table border='4' column width='500'  >
<tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#33ccff"><center>User Settings</center></td></tr>
<td>
Username   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
     required value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>"</><br><br>

Password   <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"
     required value="<?php echo base64_decode($row['password']);?>"</><br><br>

Email   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"
     required value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"</><br><br>

FBS <select name="FBS">
    <option value="True">True</option>
    <option value="False">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['FBS'];?></option>
  </select><br><br>

MBS  <select name="MBS">
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['MBS'];?></option>
  </select><br><br>

CET    <select name="CET">
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['CET'];?></option>
    </select><br><br>

Jurisdictions   <input type="text" name="jurisdictions" placeholder="Jurisdictions"
      value="<?php echo $row['jurisdiction'];?>"</><br><br>

Landing Page    <select name="pageafterlogin">
    <option value="../CET/dayreport.php">CET Day Report</option>
    <option value="../FBS/dayreport.php">FBS Day Report</option>
    <option value="../MBS/dayreport.php">MBS Day Report</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['pageafterlogin'];?></option>
    </select><br><br>


Is Admin    <select name="adminuser">
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['adminuser'];?></option>
    </select><br><br>

Access Master Name Search    <select name="InventorySearch">
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['InventorySearch'];?></option>
    </select><br><br>

Inactive    <select name="Inactive">
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
    <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row['Inactive'];?></option>
    </select><br><br>


</table>

<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div>

                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                  </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->


<!--End Main Content-->

        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

      <footer class="main-footer">
       <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">

          <b> Analytics Version</b> <?php echo $version ?> | 
          <a href="../../CET/appversions.php" >SS App versions</a>
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2018 <a href="http://www.MEBallway.com">MED Allway, Inc</a>,</strong> All rights reserved.
      </footer>

    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src='../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js'></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've included some error output code to see if anything comes up but I'm getting nothing with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Edited to fix some typos found. Still not working as expected

Comment: Are you missing a space between  ‘$Inactive’ and your Where clause in the update query?

Comment: Also, add the lines ‘$arr = sqlsrv_errors();’ and ‘foreach ($arr as $value) { echo $value; }’

Comment: Never used those before so I wasn't sure where to add it so I added it below sqlsrv_query($Sconn, $update) ;. It outputs "Array" only.

Comment: I misread the documentation on that, (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php). You are correct in the placement of it. Remove the foreach loop entirely and instead use ‘var_dump($arr);’. This will show any SQL error that may be there, or NULL if no error

Comment: I changed it as you described and came back with 'NULL'.
 Just FYI I added a raw $update statement with values not deriving for the POST data and that did execute and change the records in SQL. Seems like it's screwed up from the POST values to the $update statement. I may be wrong but that's from testing

Comment: ‘var_dump($_POST);’ to check the values of post would be my next step, rule out any post variable name errors.